# Ambiguous function arguments

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

The example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_a_table(id int, name text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE a_table 
    SET name = name
    WHERE id = id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

cause this error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "name" is ambiguous
LINE 2:   SET name = name
                     ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
```

It is clear that I can correct this by changing the names of arguments. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Changing the name of the argument is the only sensible solution to this problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Generally it is a bad practice in programming to use the same name for two different objects. You should not do it and the change of the arguments names is the best solution. However, Postgres leaves the door open (for the compatibility with older versions). You can set the [configuration parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html):

```
set plpgsql.variable_conflict to use_variable;
```

Possible values of the parameter: `error` (default), `use_variable` or `use_column`.

It is also possible to set the parameter only for a given function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_a_table(id int, name text)
RETURNS void AS $$
#variable_conflict use_variable
BEGIN
    UPDATE a_table 
    SET name = name
    WHERE id = id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly qualify ambiguous names, which is a better solution than the above one. The qualified names are of the shape `<function_name>.<parameter_name>`, for example `update_a_table.id`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_a_table(id int, name text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE a_table 
    SET name = update_a_table.name
    WHERE a_table.id = update_a_table.id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I am sorry, but disabling variable_conflict isn't good idea (not without STRONG WARNING). The solution should be using qualified names always.

Comment: @PavelStehule - Thank you, I have added two words about it.

Comment: Second solution is not working for me. ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "update_a_table"

Comment: @DominikK - ask a question with a sample data and your query. You can use [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17) to show the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I have found the problem pretty fast, I can't even remember anymore where my mistake was.

Comment: I had the same issue as @DominikK. What solved it for me is removing the schema name from the function reference. I. e., I was referencing a variable "password" in the function "auth.check_password", so I referenced it as "auth.check_password.password", which gave me the "missing FROM-clause". Using just "check_password.password" worked. (Sorry if thread-highjacking, but this is pretty subtle so I figured someone down the line might like to know.)

Comment: @EleanorHolley - that is a misunderstanding. There is no `<schema_name>` in the qualified names, you should use `<function_name>` instead. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It was my mistake; I only commented because I figured someone else could benefit from my mistake.

Answer (score 7):

This error is safer against to terribly difficult detectable bugs. The PLpgSQL good style requires

1. using qualified names everywhere in any embedded SQL - for access to function's parameters use a pattern `function_name.parameter_name`
2. previous versions of Postgres didn't this detection, and only one protection was using variables with special prefix. Usually is used '_' as prefix.  The rule is simple - when your function contains embedded SQL, then all of the variable and parameter names should start with '_'.  This is safer against name collision and it increase a readability, because you can see quickly what is a variable and what is a SQL identifier.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not quite understand. Where can I find information about special prefixes? And what is an embedded SQL?

Comment: the prefix '_' isn't special - it is usually used - http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29#Recommendation_for_design_of_stored_procedures_in_PL.2FpqSQL_language . Lot of recommendations are shared with Oracle's PL/SQL. 

Embedded SQL is any SQL statement used in PLpgSQL as first class object (the integral part of language).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_a_table_1(int,text)
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE a_table 
    SET name = $2
    WHERE id =$1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> You can create a function w/o specifying argument(s) name, in your
>   case you have 2 args so you just need to access them by providing its
>   index (`$1` and `$2`) but IMO its not a good idea when you have many
>   args to pass(*for example a function with 10 or 10+ args it may
>   confuse you*)