# Postgres Procedure: More than one row error only in the context of a procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `roles` and `permissions`, and created a many-to-many `roles_permissions` table.
A permission has a unique index on `scope`+`name` (e.g. scope="domains", name="view").

I created a `procedure` that I can pass it the role name, and permission scope and name, and it should find these values in the `roles` and `permissions` table, and create a many-to-many record.

My problem is that if a permission name appears more than once, I receive error:
`ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.
This shouldn't happen, as `scope`+`name` are unique (enforced by index). So a permission name may appear more than once, but always with different scopes.
Even weirder, when I'm "manually" executing the SQL that does the insert, without calling the procedure, it works fine. The error only happens in the context of the procedure.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE link_permission(scope text, name text, role text) AS
$$
    INSERT INTO roles_permissions (role_id, permission_id)
    SELECT
        (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE name=role),
        (SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE scope=scope AND name=name)
        -- the above row is the cause for error, even though scope+name are unique.
        -- if I add LIMIT 1, the error is solved, but not sure why I need it.
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

any ideas?

Comment: i stumbled over the same problem, but as long scope and name have not an unique constarint, nobody can guarantee that there will be two or three over the years

Comment: This might be a name resolution problem. Try to qualify names, like `permissions.score = link_permission.score`, `link_permission.name = roles.role` etc.

Comment: [Ambiguous function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748150/1995738)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm hmmm interesting. I finally took another approach: using the arguments by index ($1, $2...)

Comment: @user1102018 Makes sense. Less verbose but I think harder to read too. I do much prefer however to not reuse the same names for different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by replacing the argument names with indexes:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE link_permission(scope text, name text, role text) AS
$$
    INSERT INTO roles_permissions (role_id, permission_id)
    SELECT
        (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE name=$3),
        (SELECT id FROM permissions WHERE scope=$1 AND name=$2)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Your solution actually just avoids the problem. The real problem is poorly names parameters.  The expression `WHERE scope=scope AND name=name)` is **always true**. The reason being since you did not qualify the operand each expression refers to the the same variable. The easiest option is provide a different parameter name (like p_score and p_name) the the expression becomes `where score = p_score ...`. The other option is to fully qualify the variables/columns (as @ Stefanov.sm suggested above).